# new row add in an ng-repeat other function

Tags: angularjs

i am using ng-repeat my requirement is new row enter in ng repeat other function run automatically.

```html
<span ng-repeat="sal in studentAttendanceList">
              {{sal.name}}       {{sal.class}}        {{sal.rolenumber}}
</span>
```

controller.js

```js
var studentList = Firebase.get('studentAttendanceList', 'name', $stateParams.chatId);
studentList.$loaded().then(function() {
  $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollBottom(true);
  $scope.studentAttendanceList = studentList;
});
$scope.studentAttendanceListalert = function() {
  alert(add new enter);
}
```

if add new enter alert comes up. how it works in angularjs.

Comment: question is unclear. do u need to add a new row to `ng-repeat` once `studentAttendanceList` execute ??

Comment: no when new row show also show alert  new row added

Comment: you are getting the data from DB right. so do u need to show alert for each and every record once you get data from DB

Comment: yes im using firebase real time data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show an alert every time a new row added then use watch to monitor the changes

```
$scope.$wacth('studentAttendanceList',function(oldVal,newVal){
 if($scope.studentAttendanceList && $scope.studentAttendanceList.lenght > 0){
   if(newVal.length > oldVal.length){
    alert("new row added ")
   }
 }
})
```

Comment: where to get oldvalue and newvalue?

Comment: by default, watch passes these params. u don't need to worry about them. is basically pass the modified value and previous value

Comment: on app load face this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: studentAttendanceList  not define error when i user $scope with it.then alert cont work

Comment: it should be `$sccope.studentAttendanceList` i update it

Comment: $watchCollection use this instead of $watch

Comment: @ sachila ranawaka bundle of Thanks

Comment: @Hassan Abbas no prob make sure to upvote and mark as right answer if this helped :D

Answer (score 2):

```
$scope.$watchCollection('studentAttendanceList',function(oldVal,newVal){
if($scope.studentAttendanceList && $scope.studentAttendanceList.lenght > 0){if(newVal.length > oldVal.length){ alert("new row added ")}}})
```